# Apache closing TLS connection after first HTTPS request

Tags: apache, ssl, https, schannel

I'm using a custom HTTP/1.1 client to connect to my apache server through HTTPS. This client requires the connection to be kept alive for at least 2 HTTP requests. However, I noticed that when using HTTPS, the web server will close the TLS connection after only one HTTP request even though keep-alive should be the default for HTTP/1.1 (when connecting to the same server through HTTP, the connection will be kept alive).

The concrete error that the client encounters is that the [Windows API handling the secure connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/decryptmessage--schannel) will return `SEC_I_CONTEXT_EXPIRED` indicating that the remote server initiated a shutdown.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: *"This client requires the connection to be kept alive for at least 2 HTTP requests."* - this client is clearly broken since no such assumption should be made in HTTP. Client and server are free to close the connection after each response - no matter if they support keep-alive or not.

Comment: *"How can I prevent this behaviour?"* - Please see [the Apache documentation about this topic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#keepalive).

Comment: 1. I already tried to set the KeepAlive directive but it didn't have any effect.

2. How should the client behave when the server just shuts down the connection? Just establish a completely new connection?

Comment: Correct, if the server closes the connection than just create a new one for the next request.